# In Windows, is there a difference between UuidFromString and CLSIDFromString?

Tags: c++, windows, guid, uuid, clsid

I would just like to double-check which one is correct to use for internally generated GUIDs that bear no relation to COM classes.

My suspicion is that it's UuidFromString, but I keep seeing code that uses CLSIDFromString.  I have a vague recollection that CLSIDFromString may enumerate the COM classes listed in the registry, but am not sure whether this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UuidFromString` - the documentation for `CLSIDFromString` explicitly states that it's purpose is to convert strings generated by `StringFromCLSID` back into a `CLSID`.

Even if the behavior of the two functions is identical (and I suspect it may not be - consider, for example, that `CLSIDFromString` can return `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` indicating the class isn't registered or `REGDB_E_READREGDB` which indicates a registry I/O error) it's good practice to distinguish between a `CLSID` and your own internal `GUID` objects.

Comment: Thanks @Nik.  Following further discussion in the office, we now suspect that the reason that CLSIDFromString would need to return REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG is that it probably accepts OLE class-names as well as GUIDs in the string parameter.
In any case, it's almost certainly safer to use UuidFromString.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Chen [answers this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151015-00/?p=91351/):

`Uuid­From­String`:

> Let's start with Uuid­From­String. It takes a string in basic form
>   without curly braces. As a special case, if you pass NULL instead of a
>   valid string pointer, the function still succeeds and sets the result
>   to GUID_NULL.

`CLSID­From­String`:

> Slightly more complicated is CLSID­From­String. In addition to
>   accepting a brace-enclosed string (which is treated as a GUID), it
>   also accepts a ProgId. In the ProgId case, it returns the CLSID
>   associated with that ProgId.